# While Dynamically loading Treestore using Ajax proxy child nodes arent appearing

Tags: javascript, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I want load a Treestore using ajax proxy.But it shows only root node in user interface.
Json coming from server as response looks correct and no error in console.
I want to load the root node also from server side response but though json appears correct it doesnt appear in the user interface.

```
{"result":{"text":"ABC","leaf":false,"expanded":true,"children":[{"text":"Dashboard","leaf":false,"expanded":false},{"text":"Report","leaf":false,"expanded":false},{"text":"Chart","leaf":false,"expanded":false}]}}

var model=Ext.define('TreeModel',{
        extend:'Ext.data.Model',
        fields:[{
            name:'text',
            type:'string'
        },
        {
            name:'leaf',
            type:'boolean'
        },
        {
            name:'expanded',
            type:'boolean'
        }],
         proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'FetchTreeChidren',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'result'
                }
         }
    });

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
        model:model 

    });

    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'FetchTreeChidren',
        params: {
           level:'level1'
        },
        async:false,
        success: function(response){
            var treejson = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
            store.setRootNode(treejson);


        }
    });
    var lefttree=Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
        region:'west',
        height:screen.height-150,
        title: 'Simple Tree',
        width: 200,
        height: 150,
        store: store,
        rootVisible: false,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
    return lefttree;
```

please help me out.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
 var store  = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
                                model:model 
                                proxy: {
                                    type: 'memory'
                                },
                                root: {
                                    expanded: false,
                                    children: childreanArr
                                }
                            });
```

and change

```
store.reconfigure(treejson);
```

inside the success. This work for me